# Can `shred` show estimate remaining time?

Tags: shred

I used `-vfz` and it shows the size and percentage of current wiped amount, but I would like to see the remaining time. I think I can calculate time myself, because it seems that it wipes about 630 MB per second, but automatic calculation would be nice.

Comment: Have you checked its `man` page or `shred --help`?

Comment: shred does not have it and any program that does it will usually be very inaccurate, since HDD/SSD speed is not constant at all. Caches can also get in the way sometimes, so if ETA is more important than overall performance, `pv --direct-io` can sometimes help get a better estimate. If your real problem is that shred takes way too long, just make it a single pass instead of multiple passes. ;-) For SSD there is also fstrim / blkdiscard, much faster than doing a zero pass with shred…